# Create folder with batch but only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can anybody tell me how to do the following in in a Windows batch script?  (`*.bat`):

- Create a folder only if it doesn't already exist

In more detail, I want to create a folder named `VTS` on the `C:\` drive, but only if that folder doesn't already exist.  I don't want to overwrite the contents of the folder if it already exists and the batch is executed.

Comment: How About This ?  `if not exist "%Folder%" mkdir "%New-Folder%"`

Answer (score 785):

You just use this: `if not exist "C:\VTS\" mkdir C:\VTS` it wll create a directory only if the folder does not exist.

Note that this existence test will return true only if VTS exists and is a directory.  If it is not there, or is there as a file, the mkdir command will run, and should cause an error.  You might want to check for whether VTS exists as a file as well.

Comment: Except that it's wrong. You have to check for the NUL device, otherwise it won't work. See my answer three years earlier than this one.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk This works on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 as far as I can tell from testing, and I'd be very surprised if it doesn't work at least back to XP and up to Windows 10. Can you provide the conditions when this doesn't work?

Comment: @jpmc26 testing for NUL is to make sure you test for a directory. Otherwise the condition might evaluate to true, even it is a regular file. That is the difference.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk Is adding a trailing slash is sufficient for that? That seems to distinguish between files and directories correctly, but there is a weakness in that if the file is not detected, creation of the directory will fail. I suspect this is a problem with testing for `NUL`, too.

Comment: @jpmc26 You are right, a trailing slash does the job and is actually preferable since it works with quotes (thus allowing you to have spaces in the directory path). To distinguish between either file/directory, this will work: `if exist "a" if not exist "a\" (echo "it's a file") else (echo "it's a dir")`. About your last sentence, I suspect something is wrong with your batch file elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk the article mentioned FAT format. Does it work under NTFS?

Comment: Something to note is that when creating folders with spaces in their names, even if it's from a variable, always enclose the target directory with quotation marks, for example:
`MKDIR "!pathYouWantToCreate!"`

Answer (score 266):

```
if exist C:\VTS\NUL echo "Folder already exists"

if not exist C:\VTS\NUL echo "Folder does not exist"
```

See also https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/65994

(Update March 7, 2018; Microsoft article is down, archive on https://web.archive.org/web/20150609092521/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/65994 )

Comment: Personally I'd prefer this since it does not set %errorlevel% when dir already exists (Agent_9191's answer returns an error code of 1)

Comment: It's also nice and generic and can be applied to every other action you want to conditionally do :)

Comment: The article has some extremely convoluted information about what drive formats this works for and doesn't.

Comment: I don't know why, but this doesn't work for me:
`@echo off
if exist C:\Dropbox\Target\SplitBins9x55\NULL echo "Folder already exists, Skip 1"`
`if not exist C:\Dropbox\Target\SplitBins9x55\NULL mkdir C:\Dropbox\Target\SplitBins9x55`

Comment: @YouHaveaBigEgo `NUL` is with one L.

Comment: If your location has spaces, you are out of luck with this one. `if exist "C:\V T S\NUL"` won't work correctly. In this case, skip the `NUL` portion altogether and simply do `if exist "C:\V T S\"`.

Comment: Actually, although this answer is great, it does not answer to the question to "create a directory"  :)

Comment: This won't (sometimes) work in multithreaded or multiprocessed case (like make -j4). If more than one process or thread does this command simultaneously, it is fairly possible that both will first detect that directory is missing, then attempt to create it. Note that mkdir -p on Linux works fine in such a case.

Comment: Does this work in PowerShell? It says "Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement." for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on an NTFS drive. The archived article also just mentions FAT drives.

Answer (score 70):

Just call `mkdir C:\VTS` no matter what.  It will simply report that the subdirectory already exists.

**Edit:** As others have noted, this does set the %ERRORLEVEL% if the folder already exists. If your batch (or any processes calling it) doesn't care about the error level, this method works nicely. Since the question made no mention of avoiding the error level, this answer is perfectly valid. It fulfills the needs of creating the folder if it doesn't exist, and it doesn't overwrite the contents of an existing folder. Otherwise follow [Martin Schapendonk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4165472/6504).

Comment: this is a bad behavior due an unexpected error message / warning.

Comment: Calling something "perfectly valid" when it violates best practices is intellectually dishonest. As another example: When somebody asks you how to avoid a certain specific security problem, your answer shouldn't be "run the computer as an administrator" even if the question didn't explicitly specify minimum security impact as a prerequisite. :-)

Comment: @JouniHeikniemi s/best practices/Jouni's personal preferences

Comment: @dss539 It _is_ my personal preference that processes do not raise unnecessary error codes or exceptions. I also think it is a best practice, and a generally accepted one at that. You can, of course, disagree - but I would think some arguments might make your stance more understandable.

Comment: @JouniHeikniemi imo, the `%ERRORLEVEL%` is a fine way to return the result of an operation. It's very similar to `errno` in the C std library http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/
Some people could easily argue that the C std library followed/established "best practices" as defined by some group. I guess my point is that "best practices" is highly subjective, and this guy's suggestion follows somebody's best practices (e.g. C std lib and others), so to call him intellectually dishonest seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: Nothing wrong with Errorlevel or errno. They are platform-specific error messaging paradigms, and they work for the purpose they have been built for. But no matter what the platform or messaging approach is, I wouldn't recommend the "try to do this and recover if it fails" pattern when you can easily avoid - and thus legibly document - the common error case. Hence, I do find the "if not exists"-style approaches superior.

But, I don't want or care to go too deep into a debate about the formation of best practices. I had no intention of offending anyone, just wanted to clarify my downvote.

Comment: The problem with simply ignoring the error is that you don't know *why* it failed. It could have failed because the directory already existed, because the user doesn't have permissions on that directory, because the parent path didn't exist, or because the disk failed. "Create if it doesn't exist" should fail in all cases except the first. This answer results in an error in all cases, though. That's why it's unsuitable for a batch script. -1

Comment: This is the normal programming pattern. Do then test. Testing then doing requires three disk accesses. Doing then testing requires two. Testing the result of a Do (if you care) is comparing an integer rather than reading a disk when testing first. So less battery power is used, program is quicker. One core principal of programming is to conserve resources, esp on multitasking computers.

Comment: @user12431753 But there is other core principal of programming before conserve resources - Fail Fast.  Lets say you are programming car breaks. It is better to have an error on a car engine start than assume that everything went ok on start despite some error and have an unpleasant surprise on the road.

Comment: You can avoid the error level by redirecting output to nul: MKDIR Path\To\Create 2> nul

Answer (score 56):

```
mkdir C:\VTS 2> NUL
```

create a folder called `VTS` and output `A subdirectory or file TEST already exists` to `NUL`.

or

```
(C:&(mkdir "C:\VTS" 2> NUL))&
```

change the drive letter to `C:`, `mkdir`, output error to `NUL` and run the next command.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work in PowerShell? It doesn't seem to support `NUL` as an output file.

Comment: @AaronFranke https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906170/create-directory-if-it-does-not-exist/16911470#16911470

Answer (score 35):

```
set myDIR=LOG
IF not exist %myDIR% (mkdir %myDIR%)
```

Comment: As others have pointed out and you may have seen in the top rated answer, this does not work if you have a file named `log`. It's a subtle difference, but it will lead to hard-to-find bugs in your scripts.

Answer (score 25):

I use this way, you should **put a backslash at the end of the directory name** to avoid that place exists in a file without extension with the same name as the directory you specified, never use **"C:\VTS"** because it can a file exists with the name **"VTS"** saved in **"C:"** partition, the correct way is to use **"C:\VTS\"**, check out the backslash after the **VTS**, so is the right way.

```
@echo off
@break off
@title Create folder with batch but only if it doesn't already exist - D3F4ULT
@color 0a
@cls

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if not exist "C:\VTS\" (
  mkdir "C:\VTS\"
  if "!errorlevel!" EQU "0" (
    echo Folder created successfully
  ) else (
    echo Error while creating folder
  )
) else (
  echo Folder already exists
)

pause
exit
```

Comment: What is particularly interesting of your solution, is that you use `!errorlevel!`, i.e., delayed expansion. Otherwise, the variable `ERRORLEVEL` would be parsed prior to entering the first `if` (i.e., at parse time). Now it is parsed at execution time, so it can capture the result of `mkdir`. You are also correct in that, even though you test for existence, you should still test for success (think: access denied error, for instance). Very good solution compared to the others, +10!!!

Answer (score 22):

You can use:

```
if not exist "C:\VTS\" mkdir "C:\VTS"
```

You can also expand the code to replace any missing expected files.

```
if not exist "C:\VTS\important.file" echo. > "C:\VTS\important.file"
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to create a folder if it doesn't exist eh? Well, here is an example of how to do it.

First, I check to see if the folder doesn't already exist by entering this code:

```
if not exist "FOLDERPATH" ( 
    mkdir "FOLDERPATH"
)
```

So if I run the code. And if the folder already exists, It will do nothing. This is what we do if the folder already exists:

```
if exist "FOLDERPATH" ( 
    rmdir /s /q "FOLDERPATH"
    mkdir "FOLDERPATH"
)
```

Now if I run the code, It will re-create the folder if it already exists. This is the example code:

```
@echo off
cls

if not exist "C:\ExamplePath\" ( 
    echo Creating Folder...
    mkdir "C:\ExamplePath\"
    pause
)

if exist "C:\ExamplePath\" ( 
    echo Re-Creating Folder...
    rmdir /s /q "C:\ExamplePath"
    pause
)
```

Now the `if exist` part is Optional. If the folder already exists, you can jump to an label instead like this:

```
if exist "FOLDERPATH" ( 
    goto :ExampleLabel
    
    :ExampleLabel
    echo Hi.
    pause
)
```

Hopefully, this could help with your problem.

Answer (score 11):

This should work for you:

```
IF NOT EXIST "\path\to\your\folder" md \path\to\your\folder
```

However, there is another method, but it may not be 100% useful:

```
md \path\to\your\folder >NUL 2>NUL
```

This one creates the folder, but does not show the error output if folder exists. I highly recommend that you use the first one. The second one is if you have problems with the other.

Comment: What about on PowerShell?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know about PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would do this:

```sh
if not exist "C:\YourFolderPathHere\" (
mkdir C:\YourFolderPathHere\
) else (
echo Folder already exists!
)
```

Let's break that down:

1. `if not exist "C:\YourFolderPathHere\"`: this checks for the folder. The Backslash (\) after the path is very important, else it will look for a file rather than a folder.
2. `mkdir C:\YourFolderPathHere\`: Creates the directory if the above statement is true.
3. `echo Folder already exists!`: prints to console that it already exists.

Here's the same code, but with comments:

```sh
::Does the folder exist?
if not exist "C:\YourFolderPathHere\" (
::No, make it.
mkdir C:\YourFolderPathHere\
) else (
::Yes, don't make it, and print text.
echo Folder already exists!
)
```

One-line version:
`if not exist "C:\YourFolderPathHere\" mkdir C:\YourFolderPathHere\`

Haven't tested it though, so don't quote me on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm creating a folder in the context of docker from a Dockerfile to avoid build stopping in error if folder already exists on a `mkdir` command, and none of answer here worked for me, but some inspired me to try this, that works (the `RUN` is Dockerfile command that, by default on Windows docker, runs in context of cmd):

```
RUN mkdir C:\VTS & echo.
```

Comment: Thank you It works greate and what I was looking for.
and if we are not in a dockerfile simply we should run command: `mkdir C:\VTS & echo.`

Answer (score 0):

i created this for my script I use in my work for eyebeam.

```
:CREATES A CHECK VARIABLE

set lookup=0

:CHECKS IF THE FOLDER ALREADY EXIST"

IF EXIST "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\CounterPath\RegNow Enhanced\default_user\" (set lookup=1)

:IF CHECK is still 0 which means does not exist. It creates the folder

IF %lookup%==0 START "" mkdir "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\CounterPath\RegNow Enhanced\default_user\"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the following batch script
Also, you can execute more commands due to creating or not creating the folder.

```
if not exist "Folder_Path" ( 
GOTO CREATE_FOLDER_LABEL
      ) else ( 
GOTO DONT_CREATE_FOLDER_LABEL 
)

:CREATE_FOLDER_LABEL
rem all the commands which you want to execute due to creating folder goes here
MKDIR "FOLDER_PATH"
exit

:DONT_CREATE_FOLDER_LABEL
rem all the commands which you want to execute due to not creating folder goes here
ECHO "the FOLDER_PATH is already exist"
exit
```

Answer (score -5):

You can add the `/I` option to the mkdir command. The `/I` option tells `mkdir` to only create the directory if it doesn't already exist. If the directory already exists, the `mkdir` command will do nothing and continue with the next command.

```
mkdir /I dist
```