# Copying folder structure to location that doesn't exist

Tags: powershell

I want to copy a folder, complete with subdirectories, files and files within subdirectories, preserving the structure and create them in a new location that did not previously exist. This is my PowerShell code

```
Copy-Item c:\development\powershell\folderone\* c:\development\powershell\foldertwo -recurse -Container 
Copy-Item c:\development\powershell\folderone\* c:\development\powershell\folderthree -recurse -Container
```

`foldertwo` exists and is empty, `folderthree` does not exist.

If I run the script, the structure is created correctly in `foldertwo`, however `folderthree` gets created, but contains only all the files from the entire substructure, all at the root `folderthree` level. It has not recreated the subfolders within `folderone`, just put all the files at the root level of `folderthree`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: If I understand the issue correctly, you may want to look at using `Test-Path` first, and then, if it returns as `false`, create the directory, ala [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16911470/2486496) answer here.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick

Comment: I can't reproduce that behaviour, if I use `copy-item c:\test c:\test2 -recurse -container` (with no `*`) then it works and puts files in subfolders. If I try it with a `*` in the source as you have it, I get errors and it doesn't copy everything at all - but it doesn't dump things in the root. Did you try it without the asterisk in the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very basic, but fully working and tested example, building on your confirmation above that I understood the issue at-hand:

```
$folderlist = ("foldertwo", "folderthree")
foreach ($folder in $folderlist)
{
    if (!(Test-Path "C:\Development\PowerShell\$folder"))
    {
        mkdir ("C:\Development\PowerShell\$folder") | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item c:\development\powershell\folderone\* c:\development\powershell\$folder -recurse -Container
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help here...  I have one file outside my foldernames, so how can I copy it once?

Comment: This would be a good opportunity to post a new question yourself, and earn rep properly, @Underdog.  Consider reading [ask] and link to this Q&A to expand your question easier. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the question is about recreating the folder structure from [source] to [destination]. As using CmdLets is kind of overkill (and performance loss), I suggest simple batch command that may also be ran in powershell.

```
xcopy [source] [destination] /T /E
```

`xcopy` is a function to copy file and directory trees.
Help provides us info on usefult parameters on the case:

`/T`           Creates directory structure, but does not copy files. Does not
              include empty directories or subdirectories. /T /E includes

`/E`           Copies directories and subdirectories, including empty ones.
             Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T.