# Create subdirectory under each directory containing a file

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

I have a large number of photos that are contained in over 100 directories. These are all pre-installation photos. I would like to keep the existing directory structure but add a \pre and \post directory in any directory that contains a .jpg photo. I dont want a subdirectory created if a given directory only contains other directories but not files

For testing , I have a single .jpg in c:\temp\one\two\three. I ran this command in c:\temp:

```
FOR /R c:\temp %G IN (*.jpg) DO mkdir pre
```

However, it created the pre directory directly under c:\temp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is that you try to `mkdir` in a current dir. For each JPG file you find you want to [get a directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659647/how-to-get-folder-path-from-file-path-with-cmd), [switch to it (using `pushd`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd), create a `pre` directory [if it does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165387/create-folder-with-batch-but-only-if-it-doesnt-already-exist) yet, and then switch back to where you started (with `popd`).

```
FOR /R c:\temp %G IN (*.JPG) DO pushd %~dpG && if not exist pre mkdir pre && popd
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked perfectly on my test data. Before running it on a copy of my actual data I'll read through the very helpful links you included to do my best understand why your solution works