# Move files to a subdirectory

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

Using some great help ([Create subdirectory under each directory containing a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540370/create-subdirectory-under-each-directory-containing-a-file)) I added a \pre subdirectory in any directory that contained a .jpg photo.

I want to move any .jpg files from their current directory into the \pre subdirectory. The script I tried is:

```
FOR /R c:\temp %G IN (*.JPG) DO pushd %~dpG && if exist *.jpg move *.jpg pre\ && popd
```

The script moved the .jpg files. The problem is that the script moves the files then follows to the \pre directory and tries to do the move again.

The pre directories have been created using the script linked to in the first paragraph.

For example, directory A\B\C was processed to give A\B\C\pre. This script scans A/B/C and moves the .jpgs to \A\B\C\pre. It then follows the directory tree into A\B\C\pre and tries to move the .jpg files again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the following script:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Enumerate the directory tree:
for /D /R "C:\TEMP" %%G in ("*") do (
    rem // Check whether current directory is not named `pre`:
    if /I not "%%~nxG" == "pre" (
        rem // Check whether there are files:
        if exist "%%~G\*.jpg" (
            rem // Create sub-directory called `pre`:
            md "%%~G\pre" 2> nul
            rem // Move files into the sub-directory:
            move "%%~G\*.jpg" "%%~G\pre"
        )
    )
)
```

Or directly in command prompt:

```cmd
@for /D /R "C:\TEMP" %G in ("*") do @if /I not "%~nxG" == "pre" if exist "%~G\*.jpg" md "%~G\pre" 2> nul & move "%~G\*.jpg" "%~G\pre"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I used this script for my task and it worked well. The remarks were helpful so that I could understand what it was doing

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use this batch file for the file moving task.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Temp\*.jpg" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /C:"\\pre\\" /C:"\\post\\"') do (
    if not exist "%%~dpIpre\" md "%%~dpIpre"
    move /Y "%%I" "%%~dpIpre\"
)
endlocal
```

**FOR** starts in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the specified command line appended as additional arguments. So there is executed with Windows installed into `C:\Windows` in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\Temp\*.jpg" /A-D /B /S 2>nul | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /L /V /C:"\\pre\\" /C:"\\post\\"
```

**DIR** executed by the background command process searches

- in directory `C:\Temp` and all its subdirectories because of option `/S`
- just for files because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.jpg`
- and outputs in bare format because of option `/B`
- just the file names with full path because of option `/S`.

This list of file names is redirected from **STDOUT** (standard output) of background command process with redirection operator `|` to **STDIN** (standard input) of **FINDSTR** which searches

- for lines containing case-insensitive because of option `/I`
- either the literal string `\pre\` or the literal string `\post\`
- and outputs the inverted result because of option `/V`, i.e. the lines **not** containing `\pre\` or `\post\`.

So **FINDSTR** is used here as filter to get from the list of *.jpg file names output by **DIR** with full path just those file names which do not have `\pre\` or `\post\` in their path to exclude the JPEG files which are already in one of the two subdirectories with name `pre` or `post`.

`2>nul` after the arguments of command **DIR** suppresses the error message output by **DIR** if it cannot find any *.jpg file name in `C:\Temp` and its subdirectories by redirecting the error message written to **STDERR** (standard error) to the device **NUL**.

Read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operators `>` and `|` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with `findstr` with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** with option `/F` captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of started command process by **FINDSTR** and processes this output line by line after started `cmd.exe` terminated itself. It is very important here to process a captured list of file names and do not iterate over one file name after the other returned by the file system because of the files matched by wildcard pattern *.jpg are moved during each loop iteration within the directory structure. So the directory entries matching *.jpg changes on each loop iteration and therefore it is required that a list of file names is processed loaded into memory before moving the files.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores empty lines which do not occur here.

**FOR** with option `/F` would split up each line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and would assign just first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I` if not starting with default end of line character `;` in which case the line would be completely ignored like an empty line.

A file name with full path cannot start with `;`. So default `eol=;` must not be modified here. But the line splitting behavior is counterproductive because of a full qualified file name can contain one or more spaces. For that reason the option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters which disables completely the line splitting behavior.

Therefore each full file name output by **DIR** not containing `\pre\` or `\post\` in path as filtered out by **FINDSTR** is assigned to loop variable `I` one after the other.

It is checked next if there is for the current JPEG file a subfolder `pre` and this folder is created if not already existing. Then the current JPEG file is moved into the subdirectory `pre` with overwriting the file in `pre` with exactly the same file name.

So this batch file can be executed multiple times on `C:\Temp` as it ignores all *.jpg files in all subdirectories `pre` and `post`

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer and the extremely helpful references and explanatory notes. While I didn't use your script to perform the task on this occasion this will be a brilliant reference in future

Answer (score 1):

The problem of doing the operation in the new "pre" directory is solved by getting the list of directories before enumerating over them.

It might be nice to have a one-liner command to do it, but this is getting a bit more complex than what is easy to do in a one-liner.

Here is a PowerShell script that will do it. If you are on a supported Windows platform, PowerShell will be available. This script requires PowerShell 5.1 or higher. If you cannot get to the current PowerShell, the code can be changed to make it work. When you are satisfied that the correct files will be moved, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `mkdir` and `Move-Item` commands.

=== Move-JpegToPre.ps1

```
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "C:/src/t"
$extent = 'jpg'

foreach ($dir in $dirs) {
    if (Test-Path -Path "$($dir.FullName)/*.$($extent)") {
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$($dir.FullName)/pre")) {
            mkdir "$($dir.FullName)/pre"
        }
        Move-Item -Path "$($dir.FullName)/*.$($extent)" -Destination "$($dir.FullName)/pre" -WhatIf
    }
}
```

In a cmd.exe shell it can be invoked by:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File Move-JpegToPre.ps1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sorry I didn't accept this answer as the solution. There was nothing 'wrong' with your answer at all. I happened to use another suggested solution but will keep your solution in mind for when I need to perform something similar in future.